# Entity Framework 6 <-> SQL Server 2016 <-> Field DateTime for ConcurrencyCheck

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In my application, I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach, and on each table, I have a property `LastModificationTime` to check DbConcurrency.

This column in my database is of type `DateTime` (it is mandatory and I cannot use `DateTime2`).

I am using FluentApi and the declaration for each entity is like that:

```
    this.Property(e => e.LastModificationTime).HasColumnName("MODIFQUAND").HasColumnType("datetime").IsConcurrencyToken();
```

With SQL Server 2012, the update on my entity was working but I had to migrate the database to SQL Server 2016 and now the update is not working anymore because of this column.

The query to update my entity is:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ADRRESS]
SET [BO_ID] = NULL, [DN_CONCAT] = @0, [MODIFQUAND] = @1, [MODIFQUI] = @2
WHERE (([ADR_ID] = @3) AND ([MODIFQUAND] = @4))

-- @0: '  ' (Type = AnsiString, Size = -1)
-- @1: '08/05/2018 10:55:03' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @2: '5263' (Type = Int32)
-- @3: '4333555' (Type = Int32
-- @4: '15/12/2017 10:04:27' (Type = DateTime2)
```

I get this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in EntityFramework.dll
>   The entity is not found because of DateTime precision.

I don't understand what is the change in SQL Server 2016 related to my issue. I have found some similar issue but without answer or one answer should be to change the type of my column and use `datetime2` but I can't.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The code was wrong from the beginning. You can't use a time type for concurrency checks. That's what the `rowversion` type is for. It's not only that any time type has a limited resolution. If more than two connections perform updates you'll get duplicate modification times

Comment: Why don't you use the appropriate type for this job? Leave the modification time field as is but *don't* use it for concurrency

Comment: There's an [EF issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/49) that explains why this happens and why you *have* to change the type to `datetime2` if you want this to work. In short, the rounding behaviour's changed.

Comment: The issue links to [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-some-data-t) that explains what's changed in SQL Server 2016 and the extra validation steps needed when upgrading. If you don't want to change the field type or use `rowversion` you'll have to use a lower compatibility level

Comment: Remember that rowversion won't give you the last time data values changed, just when the last update occurred. I.e. If you update a field with the same value, rowversion changes. This may or may be be relevant to what you are trying to achieve.